# Facebook-ios-sdk posts to fan page succeed but didn't appear on the page

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm integrating Facebook-ios-sdk 3.1 to my iPad app under iOS 5.1. My goal is really typical: to allow users to post message/photo/video/link on a Facebook fan page. However I had this strange problem and I still can't figure out what's wrong after reading many questions/answers on Stack Overflow. Here is what's going on:

I'm using the following code to post a plain text message to the fan page, using graph API:

```
[FBRequestConnection
 startWithGraphPath:@"fan_page/feed"
 parameters:postParams
 HTTPMethod:@"POST"
 completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
                     id result,
                     NSError *error) {
     // Valid object ID of post is returned here...
 }];
```

I tested this on the simulator and everything works fine. However when I tried this code on iPad device, the problem happens: the above method seems to be successful as it returns a valid Facebook object ID. I even verified it's the valid ID by going to http://www.facebook.com/{page_id}/posts/{objectID} and make sure it's the right post. However, if I go to Facebook fan page or check the fan page feed, my post simply is NOT there! The post doesn't show up anywhere other than referred by http://www.facebook.com/{page_id}/posts/{objectID}.

Here are a few more data points that really puzzled me:

- This problem only appears on real device. On simulator, it works fine. The posts made through simulator appear on the fan page and on feed as expected.
- This problem only happens for plain text message. If I put additional keys in "postParams" such as link/picture/source to make it of type "link"/"video"/"photo" instead of "status", then the posts show up fan page and feed as expected.

I'm not sure what is going on. What's the difference between device and simulator? And why only plain text message has this problem? I even suspect Facebook may be filtering some of the posts as it suspects they are some kind of spams from mobile apps...

Any ideas and insights are helpful here. Thanks a lot!